# Закрытие активити с вводом логина

Tags: android, activity

у меня есть окно с вводом логина, логин передается в шапку выдвижного меню, я сделала выход с потверждением, выход осуществляется из главного активити, где вся соль находится, и я снова вижу активити с вводом логина. 
Как сделать так, чтобы оно тоже закрывалось?
я читала про методы с возвращением результата, пробовала, ничего не вышло.
Если в классе активити логина писать finish();, нужный текст передается и закрывается всё.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, так:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("login", "Elvira");
    startActivity(intent);
```